# Decipher this XPath expression to get full href attribute

Tags: url, xpath, scrapy, absolute

Is there a way I can get the full href attribute (https://studyacer.com/question/audit-and-assurance-services-444592) instead of a partial href? (https://studyacer.com/question/audit-and-) from this markup?

```
<td class="word-break">
    <span class="label label-success">Due in 5 days</span>
    <a href="https://studyacer.com/question/hey-greg-here-is-my-hrm522-discussion-444593">
        <strong>hey Greg here is my HRM522 discussion</strong></a>
    <small>&quot;Auditing of Organizational Ethics and Compliance Programs&quot;  Please respond to the following:...
    </small>
    <br />
    <strong>Business > Management</strong>
</td>
```

The XPath expression I have is this '//td[@class="word-break"]/a/@href' and it's just giving me a partial url. 
The site uses absolute urls (if that helps).

Edit: I am using Scrapy to implement a basic crawler. When I run

```
response.xpath('//td[@class="word-break"]/a/@href')
```

I get the partial url.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) The value must be truncated by some tools you use, there is nothing in the xpath that would principally truncate it and so nothing on your side to change that. You might (by clicking on "edit") add information about your tool(s) to the question and at what position you find the truncated value...

Comment: @stefanHegny Thanks for the welcome! I was implementing a basic crawler using Scrapy. And you are right it's the Scrapy tool that's truncating the full value.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a similar issue. Turns out that running

```
response.xpath('xpath_expression')
```

gives you a partial url in Scrapy. Especially if the url is a long one.
For the full value use extract() at the end. Like this

```
response.xpath('xpath_expression').extract()
```